# How to hide Select from gallery button in Ui Component Form Magento 2

Tags: magento2, ui

I have create A Image upload field Using UI Component. Now  I want to Hide or Delete Button. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?

Comment: yes i removed that with the help of CSS.

Comment: Thanks is there any other way to remove without using CSS.

Comment: let me know when you find out.

Answer (score 0):

For your module you should Create
 [Namespace][Module]\view\base\web\templates\form\element\uploader\image.html

`

```
<div class="admin__field-control" css="'_with-tooltip': $data.tooltip">
    <div class="file-uploader image-uploader" data-role="drop-zone" css="_loading: isLoading">
        <div class="file-uploader-area">
            <input type="file" afterRender="onElementRender" attr="id: uid, name: inputName, multiple: isMultipleFiles" disable="disabled" />
            <label class="file-uploader-button action-default" attr="for: uid, disabled: disabled" disable="disabled" translate="'Upload'" />                
            <render args="fallbackResetTpl" if="$data.showFallbackReset && $data.isDifferedFromDefault"/>
            <p class="image-upload-requirements">
                <span if="$data.maxFileSize">
                    <span translate="'Maximum file size'" />: <text args="formatSize($data.maxFileSize)"/>.
                </span>
                <span if="$data.allowedExtensions">
                    <span translate="'Allowed file types'" />: <text args="getAllowedFileExtensionsInCommaDelimitedFormat()"/>.
                </span>
            </p>
        </div>

        <render args="tooltipTpl" if="$data.tooltip"/>

        <div class="admin__field-note" if="$data.notice" attr="id: noticeId">
            <span html="notice"/>
        </div>

        <label class="admin__field-error" if="error" attr="for: uid" text="error"/>

        <each args="data: value, as: '$file'" render="$parent.getPreviewTmpl($file)"/>

        <div if="!hasData()" class="image image-placeholder" click="triggerImageUpload">
            <div class="file-uploader-summary product-image-wrapper">
                <div class="file-uploader-spinner image-uploader-spinner" />
                <p class="image-placeholder-text" translate="'Browse to find or drag image here'"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <render args="$data.service.template" if="$data.hasService()"/>
</div>
```

`

also in [Namespace]/[Module]/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js add this:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Ui/templates/form/element/uploader/image.html':'[Namespace]/[Module]/templates/form/element/uploader/image.html'
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

use below ui component

in your ui file use below code

```xml
<field name="image">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">store</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Image</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
            <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
            <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/image-preview</item>
            <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="*/*/upload"/>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

for the `previewTmpl` you can refer to the `Magento_Catalog/image-preview` template and add into your module and modify as per your preferance

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/web/css**

**custom.css**

```
/* Hide Upload Button  */

input[name="upload_image"] + label.file-uploader-button {
display: none;
}

/* Hide Select from Gallery Button  */

input[name="upload_image"] + label.file-uploader-button + label.file-uploader-button {
display: none;
}

/* Hide Notes */

input[name="upload_image"] + label.file-uploader-button + label.file-uploader-button + p.image-upload-requirements {
display: none;
}


/* Hide Image Previews */

.image.image-placeholder {
    display: none;
}
```

Here *upload_image* is form field Key name.

> **Add Above CSS to your layout File**

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="VendoreName_ModuleName::css/custom.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
            ......................
            ......................
            ......................
    </body>
</page>
```

***I Hope This Helps You***